# How to avoid adding a 'root' scala sbt project in IntelliJ when defining github dependencies?

Tags: scala, github, intellij-idea, sbt

I'm using IntelliJ with SBT plugin and I've added the following lines to `build.sbt` in order to add a dependency to a private github repository:

```
lazy val g = RootProject(uri("ssh://git@github.com/XXXX/myrepo.git"))

lazy val root = project in file("myproject") dependsOn g
```

After running sbt, my referenced project is successfully cloned, but build fails due to output path clashes between my base project and a `root` project that is automatically added each time I refresh sbt after modifying `build.sbt`.

Comment: Can you add more information on what the clash is?  I'm not sure I understand the behavior that's happening.

Answer (score 3):

I was having this same issue awhile back.

I'm not sure what causes it but I know that if you use the [multi-project setup](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Getting-Started/Multi-Project.html#default-root-project) for sbt (`root/project/build.scala`) instead of the simple one (`root/build.sbt`) Intellij respects your settings.

Try the multi-project setup like this and see if it solves your problem:

```
import sbt.Keys._
import sbt._

lazy val g = RootProject(uri("ssh://git@github.com/XXXX/myrepo.git"))

object MyProjectBuild extends Build {
  lazy val project = Project("myproject", file(".")) // <-- Make sure to name your project what you want the module to be named
    .settings(
      name := "myproject", // <-- Same here
      version := "1.0",
      scalaVersion := "2.11.4",
      libraryDependencies ++=Seq(
        "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.11" % "2.2.0" % "test",
      )
    ).dependsOn(g)
}
```